# Change the filename of the spark streaming output

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The below simple program reads from kafka stream and writes to CSV file every 5 mins, and its spark streaming. It generates file with the naming convention **part-00000-f90bbc78-b847-41d4-9938-bdae89adb8eb.csv**  , is there a way I can change the name to include a "DATETIMESTAMP" + GUID

Please adivse. Thanks.

I was able to find the list of options for DatastreamReader, but nothing for DatastreamWriter

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamReader.html#csv-java.lang.String-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length == 0)
        throw new Exception("Usage program configFilename");
    String configFilename = args[0];

    addShutdownHook();

    ConfigLoader.loadConfig(configFilename);
    sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName(TestKafka.class.getName())
            .master(ConfigLoader.getValue("master")).getOrCreate();
    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel(ConfigLoader.getValue("logLevel"));

    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();
    System.out.println("Spark context established");

    DataStreamReader kafkaDataStreamReader = sparkSession.readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ConfigLoader.getValue("brokers"))
            .option("group.id", ConfigLoader.getValue("groupId"))
            .option("subscribe", ConfigLoader.getValue("topics"))
            .option("failOnDataLoss", false);
    Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = kafkaDataStreamReader.load();
    rawDataSet.printSchema();
    rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("rawEventView1");

    rawDataSet = rawDataSet.withColumn("rawEventValue", rawDataSet.col("value").cast("string"));
    rawDataSet.printSchema();
    rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("eventView1");
    sqlCtx.sql("select * from eventView1")
            .writeStream()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", "~")
            .option("checkpointLocation", ConfigLoader.getValue("checkpointPath"))
            .option("path", ConfigLoader.getValue("recordsPath"))
            .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
            .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(Integer.parseInt(ConfigLoader.getValue("kafkaProcessingTime"))
                    , TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .start()
            .awaitTermination();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a provision for changing the format of part files in structured Streaming which uses ManifestFileCommitProtocol that tracks the list of valid files the job writes to. Target part file's name is combination of split,uuid and extension and this is followed for avoiding collisions.

Source:https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/20adf9aa1f42353432d356117e655e799ea1290b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala#L87

Answer (score 2):

1) There is no direct support in saveAsTextFile method to control file output name. You can try using saveAsHadoopDataset to control output file basename.

e.g.: instead of part-00000, you can get yourCustomName-00000.

Keep in mind that you cannot control the suffix 00000 using this method. It is something spark automatically assigns for each partition while writing so that each partition writes to a unique file.

In order to control that too as mentioned above in the comments, you have to write your own custom OutputFormat.

```
SparkConf conf=new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("yello");
JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JobConf jobConf=new JobConf();
jobConf.set("mapreduce.output.basename", "customName");
jobConf.set("mapred.output.dir", "outputPath");

JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("inputDir");

input.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf);
```

2) A workaround would be to write output as it is to your output location and use Hadoop [FileUtil.copyMerge function](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil&method=copyMerge) to form merged file.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in structured streaming ... like how @VishAmdi mentioned ... we have a separate job that takes care of this for now ...

Comment: Well in structured streaming if you want to change the o/p file name you can define your own partitioning and add that partitioning as a separate column in final dataframe and then try to write to your storage(cloud or local). A sample code can be:

Comment: dataFrame
            .select(functions.col("*"), yourUDF for adding partitioning column eg. based on timestamep).as(partitionIndexColName as "_part_index_or_whatevevr"))
            .repartition(functions.col(partitionIndexColName))
            .writeStream.partitionBy(partitionIndexColName)
            .format("parquet")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpointing path")
            .option("path","your storage path")
            .start()